# Python - pyplot - Seeing all values of the x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

for personal project, I'd like to show a bar graph as shown in the picture.
The problem is that the string texts written on the x axis are not totally visible so I was wondering if a specific function was able to make sure the entire values are visible.

[image: The graph I have]

Comment: Use `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.show()`

Comment: It returns the mistake : 'Tight layout not applied. The left and right margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all axes decorations'

Comment: That means that your labels are so large that they won't fit even when doubling the size of the surrounding plot. You need to use shorter labels (or maybe put extra newlines inside the labels)